# Attaching email not working from Android 30

Tags: android, email-attachments, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid application that sends logs(saving file to logcat) via email using [Email composer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) The email is working fine till Android 10. However, I am facing a problem on Android 11. When attaching the logs to the email, nothing happens. I've been researching a little and saw that it may be related to the permission to access the internal storage of the device on devices with version of android 11. I have tried "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" but then it is a sensitive permission which cant be used.

Below is my code for attaching email:

```
private void setAttachments (JSONObject params, Intent draft) {
    JSONArray attachments = params.optJSONArray("attachments");
    ArrayList<Uri> uris   = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    AssetUtil assets      = new AssetUtil(ctx);

    for (int i = 0; i < attachments.length(); i++) {
        Uri uri = assets.parse(attachments.optString(i));
        if (uri != null && uri != Uri.EMPTY) uris.add(uri);
    }

    if (uris.isEmpty())
        return;

  // uris = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.sap.cloud4custex.emailcomposer.provider", );
    draft.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
            //.setType("*/*")
            .setType("message/rfc822")
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    if (uris.size() > 1)
        return;

    draft.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));
}
```

Saving file to logcat:

```
public void createLogs() {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/c4cex");
        File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/logs");

        File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "c4cex.txt");
        //File preLogonLogFile = new File(logDirectory, "preLogonLogs.txt");

        // create app folder
        if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        // create log folder
        if (!logDirectory.exists()) {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        try {

            //  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f  " + logFile);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r 2048 -n 4"); // -r amount of bits to write, -n amount of logs to rotate
            //preLogonLogFile.createNewFile();
            //Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + preLogonLogFile + " -r 2048 -n 5"); // -r amount of bits to write, -n amount of logs to rotate

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
            if(!appDirectory.mkdir())return;
        }` Adapt the others too.

Comment: We cannot see what you have in your uri list and how you use FileProvider there.  There is too much unclear.

Comment: @blackapps, am using https://github.com/mihaistoicaselfpay/cordova-plugin-email-composer. Hopefully this helps you out